# UITableView clips to bounds while animating

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITableView with some cells that have shadows.
When I make a pan gesture to see the row actions of any cell, the table view clips the bounds of the cell until the gesture is finished.

I have `clipsToBounds` set to `false` on my cell's `contentView` and its superview, and also for the table view.

My code for the custom cell:

```
var isExpanded: Bool = false

@IBOutlet weak var shadowView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var fullContainer: UIView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    reloadUI()
}

func reloadUI() {
    contentView.superview?.clipsToBounds = false
    contentView.clipsToBounds = false

    fullContainer.layer.masksToBounds = true
    fullContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 8

    shadowView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    shadowView.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
    shadowView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: fullContainer.bounds, cornerRadius: 8).cgPath
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    isExpanded = selected
    reloadUI()
}
```

code for the viewcontroller with tableview:

```
extension SecondViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
        let action = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
        return [action]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        selectedIndex = indexPath.section
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return section != 0 ? 8 : 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = UIView()
        view.clipsToBounds = false
        return view
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if selectedIndex == indexPath.section {
            return 120
        }
        return 108
    }
}
```

`SecondViewController` also has this code, because it has a pan recognizer for change between view controllers with the gesture

```
extension SecondViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        if gestureRecognizer == recognizer || otherGestureRecognizer == recognizer {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        if gestureRecognizer == recognizer{
            for cell in tableView.visibleCells {
                let location = gestureRecognizer.location(in: cell.contentView)
                if cell.contentView.layer.contains(location) {
                    return false
                }
            }
            return true
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

UITableViewCell with bounds clipped:

[image: TableViewCell with bounds clipped]

Comment: can you post some code, to try help you?

Comment: sure, I just added a lot of code

Comment: I am not sure but I think your code is overcomplicated, or I am missing something, can you tell me what is the function of `fullContainer`I had fixed your issue but I am not sure if your fullContainerView is needed for something, my solution works without it

Comment: The hierarchy is `shadowView`-> `fullContainer`
the full container is more like a "good practice" I learnt from another developer, but in this case I use it because I need rounded corners and a shadow

Comment: can you post your view hierarchy from your storyboard?

Comment: did you solve this finally?

Comment: Right now I have other assignments, so I have to work on this later

Answer (score 12):

This looks like a bug in UITableView. It can be solved with the following extension:

```
extension UITableView {
    func fixCellBounds() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            for cell in self?.visibleCells ?? [] {
                cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
                cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just call it after calling `reloadRows`/`insertRows`/`deleteRows` etc.:

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: <index paths>, with: .automatic)
tableView.fixCellBounds()
```

**Before:**

[image: cell animation before the fix]

**After:**

[image: cell animation after the fix]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. One thing I noticed in the animated GIFs, The shadow of the above cell is casted over the cell bellow. Is there a way to prevent this so that all cells appear to be on top of all the shadows?

Comment: I have another solution to this problem, but still inspired by what you described here. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66233892/8314394)

Comment: @alobaili you might be able to accomplish this by setting the `zPosition` for each cell according to its `indexPath`.