# Shadow/Cell flickers when animating the height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am having an issue with the shadow on my cells (tap GIF to see animation):

[image]

The shadow flickers when I call `beginUpdates`:

```
cell.tappedParentView
    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        cell.animate()
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()

        self.expandedIndexPaths[indexPath] = !self.expandedIndexPaths[indexPath].or(false)
    })
    .disposed(by: cell.cellBag)
```

The animation code `animate` in the cell is as follows:

```
func animate() {
    spacerViewHeightConstraint?.constant = isExpanded ? 0.0 : 8.0

    parentView.updateLayout(isExpanded: !self.isExpanded)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
           self.childViews.forEach {
               $0.isHidden = self.isExpanded
               $0.alpha = self.isExpanded ? 0.0 : 1.0
           }

         self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    isExpanded.toggle()
}
```

And `updateLayout`:

```
func updateLayout(isExpanded: Bool, animated: Bool = true) {
    stackViewLeadingConstraint.constant = isExpanded ? 8.0 : 16.0
    stackViewTrailingConstraint.constant = isExpanded ? 8.0 : 16.0
    stackViewTopConstraint.constant = isExpanded ? 8.0 : 16.0
    stackViewBottomConstraint.constant = isExpanded ? 0.0 : 16.0

    let layout = {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()

        self.shadow = isExpanded ? nil : .card
        self.backgroundImageView.alpha = isExpanded ? 0.0 : 1.0
        self.containerView.backgroundColor = isExpanded ? .clear : .red
        self.titleLabel.textColor = isExpanded ? Theme.text100 : .white
        self.descLabel.textColor = isExpanded ? Theme.text100 : .white

        self.startingLabel.alpha = isExpanded ? 0.0 : 1.0
        self.startingLabel.isHidden = isExpanded

        self.priceLabel.alpha = isExpanded ? 0.0 : 1.0
        self.priceLabel.isHidden = isExpanded

        self.showLessButton.isHidden = !isExpanded
        self.showLessButton.alpha = isExpanded ? 1.0 : 0.0

        self.stackView.spacing = isExpanded ? 8.0 : 4.0
    }

    if animated {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) { layout() }
    } else {
        layout()
    }
}
```

If I perform the animation without calling `self.tableView.beginUpdates()` and `self.tableView.endUpdates()` the flicker doesn't happen but then of course the cell height does not adjust accordingly. I'm really not sure how to fix this. All the views and cells have transparent backgrounds (only the table view background is a solid color). `clipToBounds` is off for the `view` and `contentView` in each cell/view. I have also tried using solid colors as the backgrounds but this doesn't seem to make any difference. How can I fix this?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I assume animation making re-render of the table. Shadow spreading is a kinda heavy render. So you can try to rasterize it: `shadowView.layer.shouldRasterize = true` or move the image with a shadow outside table. But it's just assuming.

Comment: Tried shouldRasterize and no change

Answer (score 7):

My answer is inspired from this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59581645/8314394)

It took me 2 days to find the answer. Finally, I noticed that when I was calling `tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)` or just simply `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()` and if pausing the view with the Debug View Hierarchy in XCode, for some reasons the cell had its `clipsToBounds = true` during the reloading process only, even if I explicitly set it to `false`.

The solution which worked for me is this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.clipsToBounds = false
    cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = false
}
```